# Bind more columns in an array of index in to one Scrollviewer WPF - C #

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I need to bind an array of objects in ItemsSource , but not bind in the standard way , ie on row , but on columns , so two different xaml objects in succession .
Let me explain, I now have solved so :

[image]

but I would need to turn the view and make it to the grid as well :

[image]

In this case I have two objects to bind to each row , so I find it hard bindare objects from the array in succession on two different columns at the same time , my xaml code :

```
<surface:SurfaceScrollViewer x:Name="listDocumentsVisibility" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,36,15,35" Background="GhostWhite" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="Both">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AttachmentsFileList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <surface:SurfaceButton Tag="{Binding ATID}" Click="Meeting_Click">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
                                                    <Image Width="26" Margin="5,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Resources/Images/icon-document-browser.png"></Image>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-30,0,0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-15,0,0" FontSize="9" Foreground="#6C6C6C" Text="{Binding LastOpenDate}"></TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-3,0,0" FontSize="9" Foreground="#6C6C6C" Text="istituto"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                                                    <Image Width="26" Margin="5,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Resources/Images/icon-document-browser.png"></Image>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-30,0,0" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-15,0,0" FontSize="9" Foreground="#6C6C6C" Text="{Binding LastOpenDate}"></TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Lato Light}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,-3,0,0" FontSize="9" Foreground="#6C6C6C" Text="istituto"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </surface:SurfaceButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </surface:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

obviously the whole is dynamic , depending on the rest call I receive.

can bind two array index , one next to another in the same row ?
Thank you

Comment: Presumo sia stato tradotto con l'aiuto di un traduttore automatico. Sfortunatamente in inglese anche leggendolo 2 volte io non sono riuscita a capire esattamente cosa significa che vuoi collegare 2 elementi di 1 array sulla stessa riga... vuoi ridirlo in italiano così magari posso darti una mano?

Comment: Si, un traduttore esatto, non ho tempo per scriverlo di mia zucca :) comunque il mio problema è che ogni riga che vado a bindare, deve avere due elementi dell'array, ma di default l'array me ne da uno ogni ciclo di index, giusto ? perciò, come posso bindare l'elemento 0, e l'elemento 1 sulla stessa riga ? calcola che poi sarà dinamico e andrà avanti con l'elemento 2 e 3...mi sono spiegato ?

Comment: E' un problema piuttosto particolare, ma non credo tu possa risolverlo direttamente così, se dovessi farlo io creerei un oggetto che contiene una coppia di dati dove andrei ad aggiungere gli elementi dell'array ricevuto e farei il binding su una collection di oggetti "coppia". Ma non essendo addentro al tuo progetto non so quanto la cosa sia applicabile.

Comment: Immaginavo fosse complessa come soluzione, online non si trova nulla, perciò mi sa che bindo due griglie, con due oggetti diversi, e li metto nella stessa scrollviewer..così risolvo, era per non impasticciare il codice, speravo in una soluzione più "nativa".

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ItemsControl` and set the `ItemsPanel` to be a `UniformGrid` with `Columns=2`, just make sure you set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` so that the items don't get stretched out and wrap the whole thing in a `ScrollViewer` if you need to:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I may have misspelled the question , but I need to bindare two objects on the same line , having an index- only cycle , how can I bindare index 0 and index 1 in the same row , in the two StackPanel ?